# Include another pdf in a box (and other details)

Tags: boxes, appendices, scaling, pdfpages

Some time ago I read a paper that was tightly based on another one. It was from the same authors so they included the previous papers as appendixes. I noticed (and liked) that these appendixes were enclosed in a box.

In my case, I am writing a technical report (*report-a*) that should include another report (*report-b*) in its appendix. Both of the are generated by LaTeX.

The result that I am looking for is that *report-b* appears in the final section of the *report-a*, inside a box. So far, I can include it with the `pdfpages` package. I have also managed to include it in a box with `fancybox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
hello
\pagebreak
world
\pagebreak

\section{Previous report}
\fancyput(3.25in,-4.5in){%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}\fancyoval(7,9.5)
}
\includepdf[pages=-]{reportb.pdf}

\end{document}
```

I have the following problems with this:

1. Page numbering is confusing: from the `includepdf` command, page numbering follows the numbering of *report-b*
2. I would prefer if *report-b* was scaled down a little bit. I could not find how to do this with `pdfpages`
3. The *report-b* is included in the page after the section title, which wastes a whole page. I would prefer if it would start right after the section title.

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

PS: I am not really sure how to tag this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use alternatively `\includegraphics`. Here an example, which includes the first 20 pages of an external document and each page scaled down to 0.75.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,pict2e}
\usepackage{fancybox,multido}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
hello
\pagebreak
world
\pagebreak

\section{Previous report}
\fancyput(3.25in,-4.5in){%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}\fancyoval(7,9.5)}
\multido{\iA=1+1}{20}{\fbox{\includegraphics[page=\iA,scale=0.75]{file}}\endgraf}

\end{document}
```

`\fbox` is only for demonstrations ...

Comment: @Herbert: What is `\endgraf` for?

Comment: @xport: same as the original `\par` but in some cases the `\par` cannot be used.

Comment: @Herbert: Thank you. With `fbox` I have no need for `fancyput`. However, the included images/pages are not centered. Tried a `\centering` with no success..

Comment: @Yuppie: put the `\centering` right before `\fbox{}`.

Comment: @Yuppie: put the whole `\multido` command into a `\begin{center}`...`\end{center}`

Comment: Thank you again. I did find that the alignment is still a bit odd, so I changed the geometry of these pages with `newgeometry`.